# System.FormatException Exception Adding User Agent in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, httpclient

I want to use the following user agent in a windows phone 8 application

```
string userAgentString = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone " + Environment.OSVersion.Version.ToString();
userAgentString += "; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; " + Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.DeviceManufacturer + ";";
userAgentString += Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceStatus.DeviceName;
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd(userAgentString);
```

but I am getting a System.FormatException, How do I properly format the user agent string. The string is suppose to be of this form:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0; Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 920)
```

this is the exception

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in System.Net.Http.DLL
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaderParser.ParseValue(String value, Object storeValue, Int32& index)
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.ParseAndAddValue(String name, HeaderStoreItemInfo info, String value)
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders.Add(String name, String value)
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaderValueCollection`1.ParseAdd(String input)
   at MyApp.Assets.Class.MyAppNetUtils.<GetRemoteStringContent>d__0.MoveNext()
```

Comment: On which line you get this exception? What is the stack trace exactly?

Comment: And what does the exception show?

Comment: I cannot see closing parenthesis in your userAgentString.
Maybe that causes the issue.

Comment: Btw, you can use String.Format to avoid such issues; as for me, String.Format is much more descriptive.

Comment: @ViktorArsanov you are right, added the closing parenthesis and cleared the issue. thanks

Answer (score -4):

you can use the php function could find your user agent by using this function

```
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
echo $user_agent;
```

Test it in your windows mobile.

Comment: You can use also a bootstrap to avoid errors from scratch https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect